# iPhone NSDateFormatter US region style

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am working on writing iPhone app.
I want to get current date as following format.

```
Tur, 18 Apr 2013 09:20:47
```

I tried with following code.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[dateFormatter release];
```

The problem is my iPhone region is not US, so I get following string.

```
木, 18 4月 2013 09:20:47
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the `locale` property of date to get it in US format

```
dateFormatter.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]
                                                                  autorelease];
```

or

```
 [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have't use NSDateFormatter from a long time but i am proving some links -

For better understanding you can refer -

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html and

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

I hope, it might help you.